# Combine data from same table into same records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The title might not be the most accurate one, but I have the following diagram:

[image]

Notice that the **CultureTranslations** table has a combined `PK` from 3 other `FK`s and an `NVARCHAR(256)` column (**ResourceKey**).

The **CultureTranslations** table holds data similar to:

```
ApplicationId | CultureCodeId | ResourceGroupId | ResourceKey | ResourceValue |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             | 1             | 1               | X           | X (US)
1             | 1             | 1               | Y           | Y (US)
1             | 1             | 1               | Z           | Z (US)
....
1             | 2             | 1               | X           | X (GB)
1             | 2             | 1               | Z           | Z (GB)
and so on...
```

where **CultureCodeId** 1 = `en-US`, 2 = `en-GB`.

The thing is that Culture `en-GB` might not have records for all equivalent `en-US` records, only for some.

How can I write a query or a view which, based on the above, will combine resources for different cultures in the same row/record?
E.g.:

```
s.ApplicationId | s.ResourceGroupId | s.ResourceKey | s.ResourceValue | d.ResouceValue |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               | 1                 | X             | X (US)          | X (GB)
1               | 1                 | Y             | Y (US)          | null
1               | 1                 | Z             | Z (US)          | Z (GB)
```

where s = source culture (`en-US`), d = destination culture (`en-GB`).

It should always show all **ResourceKey**s from the source but put `null` in the `d.ResourceValue` column where no resource has been found for that particular **ResourceKey**, **ApplicationId** & **ResourceGroupId**.

Comment: "put null in the d.ResourceValue column where no resource has been found for that particular ResourceKey, ApplicationId & ResourceGroupId" This is an outer join

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Can you be more specific, please? Thank you!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the joins and the purpose but... how do you differentiate a source and destination culture? This might be crosstab rather than an outer join problem. Can you get a result with resourcevalues on multiple lines? If so it's trivial to get them on a single line

Comment: See @SqlZim's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `left join` and putting part of your `where` clause in the `join specification` will get you the results you are looking for.

test setup: http://rextester.com/UXUZXH20794

```
create table CultureTranslation (
    ApplicationId   int not null
  , CultureCodeId   int not null
  , ResourceGroupId int not null
  , ResourceKey     nvarchar(256)
  , ResourceValue   nvarchar(256)
);

insert into CultureTranslation values
 (1,1,1,'X','X,(US)')
,(1,1,1,'Y','Y,(US)')
,(1,1,1,'Z','Z,(US)')
,(1,2,1,'X','X,(GB)')
,(1,2,1,'Z','Z,(GB)');
```

query:

```
select 
     s.ApplicationId
  ,  s.ResourceGroupId
  ,  s.ResourceKey
  ,  s.ResourceValue
  ,  d.ResourceValue
  from
    CultureTranslation s
      left join CultureTranslation d 
         on s.ApplicationId = d.ApplicationId
        and s.ResourceGroupId = d.ResourceGroupId
        and s.ResourceKey = d.ResourceKey
        and d.CultureCodeId = 2
  where s.CultureCodeId = 1
```

results:

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| ApplicationId | ResourceGroupId | ResourceKey | ResourceValue | ResourceValue |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|             1 |               1 | X           | X,(US)        | X,(GB)        |
|             1 |               1 | Y           | Y,(US)        | NULL          |
|             1 |               1 | Z           | Z,(US)        | Z,(GB)        |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: This is it! Much appreciate it! I've put the `and d.CultureCodeId = 2` in the `where` clause, and it didn't work, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

select A.*,B.* from CultureCode A
 inner join CultureCode B on 
A.ResourceKey=B.ResourceKey 
where A.CultureCodeId=B.CultureCodeId

Comment: CultureCode table does not have a ResourceKey column. Tip: Don't answer just for the sake of answering, please. Thanks